# Google maps - reuse single infoWindow for multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple markers and currently when more than one infoWindow is clicked, the other already-opened infoWindows stay open, cluttering the map. I would prefer it if I could simply reuse a single infoWindow, move it and update it's content. This is what I am attempting to do below:

```
var info = new SnazzyInfoWindow ();

        /*
         * Loop through each item in the 'features' array, including info windows, and display the marker
         */
        features.forEach(function (feature) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: feature.position,
                icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                map: map
            });

            var infoContent = feature.contentImage + feature.content;

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoCallback(infoContent, marker);
            });
        });

        function infoCallback(infoContent, marker) {

            return function() {
                info.close();
                info.setContent(infoContent)
                info.open(map, marker);
            };
        };
```

However I am receiving the error `Cannot read property 'placement' of undefined` and can't seem to figure out what's wrong here.

Note that I am using the "[Snazzy Info Window](https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window)" plugin, but I think the same would apply to the stock infoWindow.

Comment: initializing `new SnazzyInfoWindow ();` as `new SnazzyInfoWindow ({});` fixes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Inside the onClick function, when marker.addListener('click' is being executed, you don't have feature/marker. The variables are not what they were when the foreach was executed.

One trick I mostly use, is to make an array of the marker objects.  Inside the onClick you search for the 'this' marker inside the array.

Something like this:

```
var markers = [];  // store the markers in this array

features.forEach(function (feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    // first find out which marker was clicked on
    var index = markers.indexOf(this);  // this represents the marker that was clicked on
    // index should be the same index as the index for features.
    var feature = features[index];
    var marker = markers[index];
    var infoContent = feature.contentImage + feature.content;
    // now we can call infoCallback.
    infoCallback(infoContent, marker);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am still getting that placement error even after that fix. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mgz0px1r/